# Size of Data Scanned by Redshift Spectrum for a query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am querying S3 via Redshift Spectrum. I would like to know the size of data scanned for a given query.

Athena provides it in its UI whereas I don't find a direct way to find the same in Spectrum

Is there are way to find the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `select * from SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY`

It's described more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVL_S3QUERY_SUMMARY.html

You probably want to group the results by `query` or `xid` to get the summary scanned amount.

Comment: I do not see any records for the corresponding query id that I see in the Redshift console.

Comment: You can still determine which query it was based on the timestamp and the information scanned though, right? Or were you looking to automate things? In that case I don't know.